# create c++ binary with make for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, makefile

I am trying to create a binary using a *makefile* with iOS as target platform. However, I have only seen the option to use a makefile for macOS as target platform. Is there a way to this also for iOS?

Background: I am trying to embed Google's OR tools (optimization solver) to an iOS app. Those OR tools are written in C++ and require a make file for compiling. To make it more complicated, I am using Flutter for the app. Flutter uses Xcode to create the app. Due to this external build control, integrating the C++ code with a make file seems unlikely. So my plan is to create a C++ binary framework, which I can then embed as an external binary to the project in Xcode. But now I am stuck with getting an iOS target work with that make file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make allows you to do whatever you want, provided you can describe it in the makefile. Note that make doesn't help you get around the low-level details of the task (build C++ code for iOS), you have to figure it all out yourself. Make merely automates the repetitive tasks.

So the tricky part is setting up your development workflow for iOS. Find and install the iOS cross-compilation toolchain and libraries, come up with a project structure (i.e. where you keep the headers and source, where the binaries go), try to compile and link a simple "hello world" test program. To verify the result, copy the test binaries to an iOS device and run it. Once all that is clear, you can write a Makefile to automate the build process.

If you have an existing Makefile-based source code targeting a PC or Mac platform, and you're trying to compile and run it on an iOS device, then you're actually porting this project. That is potentially a much harder task to solve than writing a Makefile from scratch. You'd have to be quite familiar with your new target platform (iOS) and its development tools; the project itself and, of course, make.

See also the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I do have a Makefile-based source code. It does not have any i/o other than some input values and output to the terminal. That is why I thought porting (the C++ code) should be easy. Unfortunately, makefiles are new to me, though I did C ages ago. Are you saying, porting the makefile or porting the source code is painful? If the latter, do you expect this also for a solver taking variables as an input and as an output? Based on your 1st paragraphs and if no code porting required, would I basically need to tell in the makefile to build for iOS, not in Xcode IDE?

Comment: If this application mainly processes data and doesn't access system libraries, then it's a good start. Sounds like it's fairly independent of the target platform, so porting the code itself might not require much effort. As for the makefile, it's just a script. It doesn't have a concept of target platforms. The author has to write the logic to do the correct thing for every supported platform. You can't tell it to build for iOS unless somebody (you, presumably) has explicitly told it what to do. This starts with installing the iOS C++ toolchain and libraries, then using them in the makefile.

Comment: When porting a Makefile to a very similar platform to an existing one, you might get away with just adding the correct compiler command (and maybe the include paths for headers or libraries). But I've never worked with iOS, so I don't have experience there.